# deprecated alternative for Apache POI Elements

Tags: java, excel

can anybody help me? 
what cann i use instead of the following Elements?

1. `getCellType()`
2. `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC`
3. `CELL_TYPE_STRING`

Comment: I don't really know what the question is. There is a [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) Enum, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yess and I was about to write a Code to read the Excel file but I could Not use These tree!!